# Having trouble deploying my node.js app to digital ocean

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy my node.js application to digital ocean. Locally my app works fine when I do:

```
node server.js
```

I cloned my repository from gitlab  with ssh access and tried doing the same thing, but all the page does is being stuck on the loading stage and eventually it says that my ip address took too long to respond.

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Eventually I am planning on using something to make it run permanently but I will post a separate post for that.

I normally user my ip address:port number to try view my application.

this is my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express') ,app = express(), path = require('path'), 
socket = require('socket.io'), emailModule = require('./email.js'),
formValidationModule = require('./formValidation.js'), vimeoModule = require('./vimeo.js'),
port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


let 
    server = app.listen(port,function(){
        console.log('listening to requests...');
    }), 
    io = socket(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
    console.log('made a connection!');

    socket.on('getShortFilmsInfo', ()=>{
        vimeoModule.videos.short_films.forEach((y)=>{
            vimeoModule.getVideoThumbnail(y).then((data)=>{
                socket.emit('shortFilmsInfo', data);
            });
        })    
    });

    socket.on('getCommercials',()=>{
        vimeoModule.videos.commercials.forEach((x)=>{
            vimeoModule.getVideoThumbnail(x).then((data)=>{
                socket.emit('commercialInfo', data);
            })
        });

    });

    socket.on('email', (data)=>{
        if(formValidationModule.checkEmptyContact(data.client, data.email, data.name, 
            data.title, data.message)){
                socket.emit('invalidData');
            }
            else {
            /**
                 * * Here you need to set your email options which includes the clients email, destination email,
                 * subject and the text (the email content).
                 */
                emailModule.setMailOptions(data.email,/*'Info@project-gorilla.co.uk'*/'salay777@hotmail.co.uk'
                , data.client + ' ' + '(' +
                data.name + ')' + ' ' + data.title, data.message).then((mailOpts)=>{
                    emailModule.send(mailOpts);
                });
                console.log('email has been sent!');
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: I changed my port to 8080 and I am still having problems..

Answer (score 0):

Port on which you are running node application in digital ocean is blocked from outside access. Configure digital ocean to route any request on port `80` or `443` ( default port for http and https ) to your internal nodejs application.